# how to escape quotes in gremlin queries

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I have this query and as you firstName contains single quote Anthony O'Neil

```
:> g.addV('person')
    .property('firstName', 'Anthony O'Neil')
    .property('lastName', 'Andersen')
    .property('age', 44)
```

Any Ideas how to escape it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape the apostrophe using \

So your Gremlin becomes:

```
:> g.addV('person')
    .property('firstName', 'Anthony O\'Neil')
    .property('lastName', 'Andersen')
    .property('age', 44)
```