# How to replace single quotes (') with \' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

How to replace single quotes `(')` with `\'` in python?

Need to convert from

```
"{'fr': '', 'en': 'Title Edit 02'}"
```

to

```
"{\'fr\': \'\', \'en\': \'Changed\'}"
```

Comment: The first example is not a valid Python expression - can you provide a working code example that has the actual value you want to modify?

Comment: it's a `dict`, converted to `str` to store in the database.

Comment: why do you need so?

Comment: Gremlin is not accepting, single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483185/how-to-escape-quotes-in-gremlin-queries

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for JSON? The chance that some database expects a manually adjusted Python `str` representation are tiny.

Comment: Why does the value of en change as well in the expected output?

Comment: apache-tinkerpop gremlin " Submitting script" should be in `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
s = "{'fr': '', 'en': 'Title Edit 02'}"
s= s.replace("'","\\'").strip("\\'")
print(s) # Or Do What you need with s
```

Output: `{\'fr\': \'\', \'en\': \'Title Edit 02\'}`

Explanation: Replace all ' with '. strip() can be omitted, just a fail safe.

Answer (score -1):

Talk is cheap. Show you the code

```
str = "{'fr': '', 'en': 'Title Edit 02'}"
str1 = str.replace("\'", "\\\'")
print(str1)
```

OUT

```
"{\'fr\': \'\', \'en\': \'Title Edit 02\'}"
```